# i have written code for Post request to REST API, but it's sending GET request

Tags: php, rest, api, curl

i have written code for Post request to `REST API`, but it's sending `GET` request. I'm printing request method at the end of the code. Please help me to solve this issue. and i'm working in localhost to get the response. And the

```
$credentials = "xxxx:yyyy";
$url = "http://api.utrust.in/get/token"; 
$page = "/get/token"; 
$headers=[ 
    'POST ".$page." HTTP/1.1',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length:0',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($credentials),
    'Connection:keep-Alive',
    'Host:api.utrust.in',
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
print_r(get_headers($url));
$CurrentURL1="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];;
echo  $CurrentURL1;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Answer (score 0):

This simple Post request

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

$output=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Before php code, try it in POSTMAN , if you got output, Postman itselt you can generate PHP code.